# How TVM is different from MLIR?

Tags: deep-learning, compiler-construction, apache-tvm

As per my understanding, both TVM and MLIR are used as compiler infrastructure for deep learning neural networks. Is my understanding correct?.

And Which would be better if we are building a compiler for custom hardware that runs deep learning inferences?

Comment: [tag:tvm] appears to be meant for an Amazon web service thingy, rather than Apache TVM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this discussion helpful:
https://discuss.tvm.apache.org/t/google-lasted-work-mlir-primer/1721